# TypeScript + React: defaultProps not works for optional props in strict null checking mode

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

My TypeScript version is `2.0.10`.

The component

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface HelloProps { list?: number[]; }

export class Hello extends React.Component<HelloProps, {}> {
    static defaultProps = {
        list: [1, 2, 3]
    }
    static propTypes = {
        list: React.PropTypes.array,
        title: React.PropTypes.string
    };

    render() {
        let {list} = this.props
        return (
            <ul>
                {
                    // error here: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
                    list.map(item => (
                        <li>{item}</li>
                    ))
                }
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

The TypeScript compiler config file

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react",
        "strictNullChecks": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Note that I set `strictNullChecks` to `true` here. And the compile output:

```
ERROR in ./src/Hello.tsx
(19,21): error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

But I have set the default value for list. Is it a TypeScript bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TypeScript 3.0](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#support-for-defaultprops-in-jsx) has supported this.

Answer (score 3):

Adding an exclamation mark `!` behind `list` should help:

```js
list!.map(item => (
    <li>{item}</li>
))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way around this using the default react types on DefinitelyTyped. There is an [open ticket on github](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/11640) tracking solutions to this.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript [interface inheritance](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) is the way to go.

```
interface Props {
  firstName: string;
  lastName?: string;
}

interface DefaultProps {
  lastName: string;
}

type PropsWithDefaults = Props & DefaultProps;

export class User extends React.Component<Props> {
  public static defaultProps: DefaultProps = {
    lastName: 'None',
  }

  public render () {
    const { firstName, lastName } = this.props as PropsWithDefaults;

    return (
      <div>{firstName} {lastName}</div>
    )
  }
}
```